# `jsonwebtoken` - `decode` not readable in `Nodejs` api

Tags: node.js, jwt, express-jwt

In my `MEAN` application, I am validating the username and password. later I am trying to get the user information to display in the web page. But I am not getting the data as readable.

I don't know the issue here and the wrong what i do. any one help me.

my response api is :

```
apiRoute.get('/me', function(req, res) {
                res.send(req.decoded);
            })
```

from the `req.decoded` I am getting the result as :

```
{
  "data": {
    "iat": 1474893984,
    "exp": 1474937184
  },
  "status": 200,
  "config": {
    "method": "GET",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "cache": true,
    "url": "/api/me",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "x-access-token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0NzQ4OTM5ODQsImV4cCI6MTQ3NDkzNzE4NH0._Qs2rTaH_oCAZ0c1LOe5oFiUVOZ9jXtpWc0fSykH4Xw"
    }
  },
  "statusText": "OK"
}
```

In the data, i am not getting the user name, instead of getting some num values.

here is how i am setting the `decode` when user logs in:

```
apiRoute.use(function( req, res, next ) {

        var token = req.body.token || req.param('token') || req.headers['x-access-token'];

        if( token ) {

            jwt.verify( token, superSecret, function( err, decoded ) {

                if( err ) {

                    return res.status(403).send({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'
                    });

                } else {
                    req.decoded = decoded; //setting the value on login.
                    next();

                }

            })

        } else {

            return res.status(403).send({
                success: false,
                message: 'No token provided.'
            });

        }

    })
```

**UPDATE**

As per **hpavlino** suggession i have updated my code, and I am getting this in console, if any one find the solution let me know:

```
express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead app\routes\api.js:67:37
token is eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0NzQ5MDAzMDEsImV4cCI6MTQ3NDk4NjcwMX0.8gjrBcX6cD74pix1weqv06qoqw1xFcFHLoR3Mp2fUSE
Access token has expired
GET /api/me 200 19.364 ms - -
GET /app/views/pages/families.html 304 21.319 ms - -
GET /favicon.ico 304 5.999 ms - -
```

Comment: did you check the value of decode before assigning to req.decode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this method and it decoded right information:

```
if (token) {
  try {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(token, jwtSecret)
    if (decoded.exp <= Date.now()) {
      console.log("Access token has expired")
      return next()
    }

    console.log(decoded);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log("couldn't decode token: " + err)
    return next()
  }

} else {
  console.log("token not found!")
  return next()
}
```

Comment: I have console for token, it give correct out put, but when i console the decoded it's not readable and it look like above mesioned

Comment: I am getting error as : `Access token has expired` - then what would be the issue?

Comment: Remove part "if (decoded.exp <= Date.now()) {
      console.log("Access token has expired")
      return next()
    }" and then try

Comment: If it works when you remove this part, try to implement some other expiration check (e.g. npm package moment)